# jinja2: track previous value in for loop

Tags: python, jinja2

in a jinja2 for loop, how can I keep track of what the previous value of a variable was (for purposes of displaying breaks between "groups")? The obvious and straight-forward answer of:

```
{% set last_val='unk' %}
{% for object in data %}
    {% if object[0]!=last_val %}
        <output whatever separation code>
        {% set last_val=object[0] %}
    {% endif %}
    <other stuff>
{% endfor %}
```

...doesn't work due to jinja2's scoping rules - each new time through the loop sees the same 'unk'. How can I work around this limitation?

EDIT: I was poking around some older code of mine where I had done similar things, and *apparently* this DID work with jinja2 2.8, but broke sometime before 2.9.6. So I guess one solution would be to downgrade to 2.8 and just stay there.

Comment: It seems that division by groups should be perfomed by "model" part (by natural python code), not by "representation" part (by jinja template). Is `data` an *array*-like sequence, that is can be accessed by index?

Comment: Yes, it is. I guess I could go through the loop twice - once in python code, to split it up into a bunch of smaller lists, and once in the jinja code to display, but that would be remarkably inefficient, especially since the split is purely a "representation" thing, not a data processing thing.

Comment: As `data` can accessed by index, you could **iterate over indicies** instead of iterating over *elements*. So you could have access both to the current and to the previous element (or to the current and to the next element). As for Model-View division, not every "purely representation thing" should be in the template for view. Think about comparision of user name with 'root': this is classic example of what **shouldn't be** in a template.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: The comment about iterating over indices instead of elements could be presented as an answer. Sounds like it should work. As for the rest, when programing rules become arbitrary - representational logic goes in the template, except for *this* representational logic - I tend to start ignoring the exceptions, especially if they make my life harder. But that's a whole different discussion, and not appropriate for stack overflow :)

Comment: Looks like there may be a solution that makes everybody happy shortly: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/676

Answer (score 6):

Use "loop.previtem" .

```
{% for object in data %}
    {% if loop.index0 ==0  %}
        <output whatever separation code>
        
    {% elif loop.index0 > 0 and loop.previtem[0] != object[0]  %}
        <output whatever separation code>
        
    {% endif %}
    <other stuff>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `loop.index` starts from 1 instead of 0.  To get an index that starts from 0, use `loop.index0` instead.  So either use `loop.index0 == 0` or `loop.index == 1`

Comment: Thanks, chys. modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

jinja is not able to change the value of variable ,but you can use dictionary to change value of key .
this will work .

```
  {% set last_val={'key':'unk'} %}
  {% for object in data %}

     {% if object[0]!=last_val.key %}
        <output whatever separation code>
        {% set test = last_val.update({'unk':object[0]}) %}

     {% endif %}
     <other stuff>
  {% endfor %}
```